# How to select a visible element in Protractor with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have a SPA where there are multiple divs with the same class. I want protractor to select the visible div and click it. I keep getting the `Failed: element not visible` which makes be believe it's getting some element that isn't on this particular page (maybe?). I also get `WARNING - more than one element found for locator By.cssSelector('.myDiv') - the first result will be used` which again makes me think it's not clicking the visible one, but the invisible one.

Here is my spec:

```
describe('User actions', function () {
    it("should be able to click a my div.", function () {
    var myDiv = element(by.css('.myDiv'));
    myDiv.click();

    // some expect... haven't gotten this far yet.
});
```

**How do I select the visible `.myDiv` and click it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with angular, it is pretty common to have many layers of the same bit of html hidden, but earlier in the overall html page than the visible element you would like to work with.

For general debugging, open up your site to the position you expect your protractor test to be in, then open the html and do a search on the html for the element your protractor test is searching for. Note if it is visible or not and where it is located overall.

Consider if you would like to add a tag for different areas of the page where the element can appear, and then use parent and child selectors to get the one you'd like.

You can also use this to select just the first visible element:

```
// Takes a protractor webelement and returns the first displayed version
// Ex:
// var coolBox = $('.coolBox');
// var visibleCoolBox = getFirstVisibleProtractorElement(coolBox);
this.getFirstVisibleProtractorElement = function(selector){
    var allElementsOfSelector = element.all(by.css(selector.locator().value));
    return allElementsOfSelector.filter(function(elem) {
        return elem.isDisplayed().then(function(displayedElement){
             return displayedElement;
        });
    }).first();
};
```

Pass in any element you'd like, it will take the locator and get the first visible version of it. You can also take off the .first() portion to return an array of the visible elements to work with.

**EDIT**:

To use this, I will give a protractor+jasmine example. I thiiiink this should work given there is any number of desired elements on the page, with at least one being visible. This is off the top of my head though, so I may have made a mistake somewhere.

example_spec.js

```
var examplePage = require('./example_page.js');

describe('Extracting visible elements', function(){
    it('A visible element can be extracted', function(){
        expect(examplePage.isACoolBoxVisible()).toBeTruthy('Error: No visible CoolBoxes');
    });
});
```

example_page.js

```
var protractorUtils = require('./protractor_utils.js');

module.exports = new function(){
    var elements = {
        coolBox: $('.coolBox')
    };

    this.getVisibleCoolBox = function(){
        return protractorUtils.getFirstVisibleProtractorElement(elements.coolBox);
    };

    this.isACoolBoxVisible = function(){
        return getVisibleCoolBox.isDisplayed();
    };
};
```

protractor_utils.js

```
module.exports = new  function(){
    this.getFirstVisibleProtractorElement = function(selector){
        var allElementsOfSelector = element.all(by.css(selector.locator().value));
        return allElementsOfSelector.filter(function(elem) {
            return elem.isDisplayed().then(function(displayedElement){
                 return displayedElement;
            });
        }).first();
    };
};
```

Comment: I'm new to protractor (and a number of JS functions)... Where does this go? Before my describe in the spec file?

Comment: @Jeff I would make this a part of a "helper" library which you can require in the spec files or make available in `onPrepare()` via `global`..

Comment: Ok. Is there documentation on that? I've made a library but it uses `exports.someFunction = function ...`

Comment: Hey @Jeff, I edited my post. Please take a look at the edit portion and let me know if it answers your question. I'm not super experienced at programming, but I dont think it breaks any major standards the way I have it set up haha.

Answer (score 7):

You can [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) it out:

```
var myDiv = element.all(by.css('.myDiv')).filter(function (elm) {
    return elm.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
        return isDisplayed;
    });
}).first();
```

Comment: This worked for me superbly. Thank you very much @alecxe

Comment: Isn't `return elm.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {return isDisplayed;});` the same as just `return elm.isDisplayed()` ? All the `.then` function is doing is passing back the result it got in the first place.

Comment: @TreverShick you could be right, but I was under the impression that this `.then` was making a difference in case of using it inside `filter()` or `map()`. Have not checked that in a while though.

Comment: @TreverShick is correct. As the docs certify, "filterFn can either return a boolean or a promise that resolves to a boolean". calling `elm.isDisplayed()` will return a promise that resolves to a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

Logic and technique in my answer is actually the same but I find my solution more reusable.

define a function like below

```
getFirstDisplayed(locator: Locator) {
  return element.all(locator).filter(x => x.isDisplayed()).first();
}
```

Then just converts your statements like

`element(by.css('img[title="Delete query rule"]')).click();`

to

`getFirstDisplayed(by.css('img[title="Delete query rule"]')).click();`

This way you will click on the first displayed item