# Protractor: How to enter values when Element is not visible coz of Ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver-io

My code before clicking on the element is this:

```
<span ng-show="!Samples" class="u-pl- ng-binding" style="">898<span class="pull-right edit-icon"><i class="Samples2"></i></span></span>
```

When I click is this:

```
<span ng-show="!Samples" class="u-pl- ng-binding ng-hide" style="">898<span class="pull-right edit-icon"><i class="Samples2"></i></span></span>
```

as a result of this, when I click and then try to enter the values, element is not visible or IsDisplayed returns `false`. However, I cannot enter without clicking on it. So basically the issue is on clicking, the class value to changes to ng-hide and then I am unable to enter the values since the element is not visible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure where is an another element (most likely an `input`) becoming visible at the moment you click this element and it is becoming hidden. Locate this visible element and enter values into it.

Comment: yes, thats right. there was a TextBox opening up which i could not find. Issue is resolved.

Comment: @ArunNair : i also have a similar problem, but with a login button, how did you resolve it ?

Comment: @Emna you can either improve your locator to make it more specific and uniquely match the element, or filter only the visible element matching the locator: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33021108/771848.